# How to disable field's auoifilling in Chrome with Vaadin?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

In all input fields in Chrome appear nonsens texts - some texts, that were written in other text field. It seems, that it is connected with default IDs. It can be probably resolved for text fields with setting custom id with `setId(..)` method. But it doesn't work for datefields, comboboxes etc. while the `id` is set for the parent `div` not the input itself eg.:

```
    <div role="combobox" class="v-filterselect v-widget small v-filterselect-small v-has-width" id="Field-1553856663994" style="width: 100%;" autocomplete="off">
<input type="text" class="v-filterselect-input" autocomplete="nope" id="gwt-uid-134" aria-labelledby="gwt-uid-133" style="width: 100%;" tabindex="0" dir="">
<div class="v-filterselect-button" aria-hidden="true" role="button"></div></div>
```

Is the way in Vaadin to set `id` for inner element or to disable completion in Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

Chrome the behavior on autocomplete attribute changed a while ago, but it has been until recently we made a change in our implementation according to that in Vaadin 8.

There is lengthy discssion about this in our issue tracker;:: https://github.com/vaadin/framework/issues/11437